# Passing data into Angular 4 component that is in a package

Tags: angular

I am creating NPM packages of Angular 4 modules/components/services.  The component needs to display things that are app-specific like the user name and an environment-specific URL or two.

I'm having trouble determining how I would pass that data from my Angular 4 app into these shared components.  I tried creating a service inside the component and using Subject but that didn't work because it was creating a copy of the service for both the package component and the app component.

So my question is:  Is this even possible using Angular 4?  If so, how?

Comment: Not an expert, buy why are you declaring a provider for the service in the 3th party package module ?

Comment: It was an attempt to share data using an Observable so the component could subscribe to it and the app could set it.  But it didn't work since the services are two different copies.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need to register the service as provider instance in the package. Only as an export in the package module to be used by the package consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here.  It turns out it is possible to share a service that lives in an npm packaged Angular 4 component/module/service with your app.

What I was doing was not binding my packaged component variables correctly, i.e. using the async pipe and binding directly to the Subject<string>.  I was handling the subscribing and that didn't work properly.

Here's the html in the packaged component:

```
<p>Welcome, <b>{{fullName | async}}</b>
```

Then in the component typescript file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fullName = this.headerSvc.nameSource;
}
```

The headerSvc has this:

```
public nameSource:Subject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
```

and this (which the app calls):

```
setName(name: string) {
  this.nameSource.next(name);
}
```

Hope this helps someone figure this out.